# Tableau .. can you retain hyperlinks upon exporting to PDF?

Tags: pdf, tableau-api

Potentially dumb question, but I have a series of web links that I include as part of my enterprise wide PDF distribution, and I was wondering if there was a way to make these links retain the fact that they are clickable upon export of the PDF.

Has anyone figured out a workaround or method to make this reality?

The links work when publishing dashboards in tableau server, but again, this is PDF-specific.